# Regex: Negating characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation

quick question -

How do you create a language of strings out of say {x,y}, but negating all strings with (xy)?

**My attempt's so far:**

`\bx*[^(xy)]*y\b`   OR         `\by*[^(xy)]*x\b`    OR `\b[^(xy)][xy]*[^(xy)]*\b`

The last of which is the least restricted, but seems clumsy with the multiple usage of [^(xy)].

What is the laziest most convenient method for completely negating a string which contains (xy), but allows all other combinations?

Thanks

**Editted:** Example strings that are allowed:      xxxxxxx yyyyyyyyy  yxxxx yyyyyyxx

Example strings that are *not* allowed:  xxxxyxxx xyxxxx yyyyxyyy  yyyxyxy   etc

Comment: FYI `[^(xy)]` means "one character that is not a `(`, an `x`, a `y´ or a `)`".

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah, There's my problem. How do I correctly use the caret `^` symbol to negate a string not just a character? Is it `[^x][^y]`?

Comment: No, that's what negative lookahead assertions can be used for - see Joey's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the challenge correctly, you're describing a language of strings that can start with any number of y's, followed by any number of x's, as those are the only two characters allowed, and you can't place a y once an x has appeared because that would cause the string "xy" to appear.

```
\by*x*\b
```

Of course, I assume that you're actually looking for a more general solution for cases that aren't as simple as the one you give. In that case, a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is the easiest solution.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't notice the language limitation. My answer disappeared because it was wrong initially.

Comment: Perfect answer for my problem! But I wanted to see usage of `[^` in there, so no tick :(

Comment: tetris11: You can't really (elegantly at least) force a negative match for a *string* with a negated *character* class.

Comment: @Joey Ah, yes I realise now that positive assertion is what I was ideally looking for. `\b(?!xy)[xy]*\b` is the most correct.

Comment: tetris11: That would match words that *don't begin with* `xy`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead

```
\b((?!xy)[xy])+\b
```

Comment: I changed your `.` into `[xy]` since those are the only allowed characters. Also, you might want to substitute `\b` for the `^$` anchors since it appears the OP is looking for words in a larger string (but that's guesswork from his question which is a bit unclear).

Comment: Even with {*x*, *y*} as language `.` will work and is more concise, imho. If you got a language you don't try filtering words from a different language, usually. But yes, it's a bit fuzzy on the part of whole string vs. words.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

`\bx[^xy\s]*y\b`

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
\bx[^xy\s]*y\b

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
Match the character “x” literally «x»
Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^xy\s]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   One of the characters “xy” «xy»
   A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s»
Match the character “y” literally «y»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
-->
```

Comment: This allow `xy` and `xabcy` and lots of other "illegal" strings.

Comment: Would you please supply some sample string to match and to unmatch. So, that your requirement would be more clear. Or try this analogy: ``\bx[^put_here_what_chars_you_want_to_negate]*?y\b``...